# Extending Handlebars.js templates

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Is there a way to extend templates like in Django? My base template has a header that only needs to be a few pages. I'd like to change that for the the other templates.

Something similar to

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
    ...
{% endblock %}
```

I'm using Ember.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know this notation does not exist, also i haven't seen the concept of inheritance on handlebars templates layer.

However, i can think of two ways to achieve what you want,

**1.** using the `{{partial}}` helper http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/

The `{{partial}}` helper can render the header part and it can be included only on those templates of the pages that require the header.

**2.** using layouts http://emberjs.com/guides/views/adding-layouts-to-views/

Have two layouts one with the header and another without it, then specify on the pages/views that need the header the corresponding layout using the `layoutName` property.

Comment: What is the difference between a partial and a component?

Comment: @A23 a component is like a `view` but somewhat more generic in fashion, as custom element tags can be specified, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593424/views-vs-components-in-ember-js also check out this for difference between partial and view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982257/ember-js-handlebars-render-vs-outlet-vs-partial-vs-view-vs-control

Comment: @A23 also to simplify things a bit i think of `partial` as something stateless without any backing classes that is simply concerned with rendering a template in place.

Comment: This seems like what I'm looking for. Thanks @melc!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same as I come from the same Django background. Here I've found exactly what you are looking for. It uses another module from `npm` called [Handlebar-layouts.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars-layouts) which is really useful.