# Is there a Handlbars equivalent to Jades extend

Tags: express, handlebars.js, pug

I'm contemplating moving the tempating language of my express app from Jade to Handlbars, and I'm wondering if there is an equivalent to the Jade extend directive in handlebars.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending Handlebars.js templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474194/extending-handlebars-js-templates)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As i can see, in the repository of handlebars tells you that exist a dependencie for handlebars that can enable you to extends blocks. You can found more information [here](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/#handlebars-in-the-wild) and [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars-layouts).

**layout.hbs**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    {{#block "head"}}
        <title>{{title}}</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/screen.css" />
    {{/block}}
</head>
<body>
    <div class="site">
        <div class="site-hd" role="banner">
            {{#block "header"}}
                <h1>{{title}}</h1>
            {{/block}}
        </div>

        <div class="site-bd" role="main">
            {{#block "body"}}
                <h2>Hello World</h2>
            {{/block}}
        </div>

        <div class="site-ft" role="contentinfo">
            {{#block "footer"}}
                <small>&copy; 2013</small>
            {{/block}}
        </div>
    </div>

    {{#block "foot"}}
        <script src="assets/js/controllers/home.js"></script> 
    {{/block}}
</body>
</html>
```

Here we define a basic layout where you can extend others html from this one.

**page.html**

```html
{{#extend "layout"}}
    {{#content "head" mode="append"}}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/home.css" />
    {{/content}}

    {{#content "body"}}
        <h2>Welcome Home</h2>

        <ul>
            {{#items}}
                <li>{{.}}</li>
            {{/items}}
        </ul>
    {{/content}}

    {{#content "foot" mode="prepend"}}
        <script src="assets/js/analytics.js"></script>
    {{/content}}
{{/extend}}
```

In this file you set all the data you want to extend from layout.

**The .js file**

```js
var handlebars = require('handlebars');
var layouts = require('handlebars-layouts');

// Register helpers 
handlebars.registerHelper(layouts(handlebars));

// Register partials 
handlebars.registerPartial('layout', fs.readFileSync('layout.hbs', 'utf8'));

// Compile template 
var template = handlebars.compile(fs.readFileSync('page.html', 'utf8'));

// Render template 
var output = template({
    title: 'Layout Test',
    items: [
        'apple',
        'orange',
        'banana'
    ]
});
```

1. Require *handlebars* and *handlebars-layout*
2. Register the helper in the handlebar as a layout.
3. Register partials set the file *`layout.hbs`* as a "module" called 'layout', then in the page.html you set the extension from 'layout'
4. Compile in template the extension *page.html*.
5. Render template passing data from js to the file.

Comment: when referring to external ressources you should always provide an example in order to create an acceptable answer. cheers.

Comment: @GottZ Thanks, I copy and paste code from the resources i have posted but i explain a little of how this work. I wish this can help!

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a webpack solution. I leave a snippet of code with my configuration:

```
webpack.config.js

...
const fs = require("fs")
const HandlebarsPlugin = require("handlebars-webpack-plugin")
const HandlebarsLayouts = require('handlebars-layouts');

module.exports = {
    ...,
    plugins: [
        ...,
        new HandlebarsPlugin({
            ...,
            onBeforeSetup: function(Handlebars){
                Handlebars.registerHelper(HandlebarsLayouts(Handlebars));
                Handlebars.registerPartial('default', fs.readFileSync('path/to/layout.hbs', 'utf8'));
            }
        })
    ]
}
```

**References:**

[Handlebars Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/sagold/handlebars-webpack-plugin)

[Handlebars Layouts](https://github.com/shannonmoeller/handlebars-layouts)