# What is components, templates, view in ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I tried going through the official documentation for getting to know about the concepts of views, templates, handlebar, and component in ember.js but not able to get a clear idea of how the above are used in different scenarios. If anyone can give me a real life analogy, it would be really great. I'm sorry but I'm very new to JS and ember. Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of just reading the docs try going through some tutorials.

Comment: I went through a few examples Dave, still I'm not understanding properly. Any little help would help me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the difference between components and views I suggest you read the following page.

[Ember View and Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593424/views-vs-components-in-ember-js)

Components are reusable controls. Like a star rating button or anything like that.

In the template you can specify the position of the elements in HTML. In Ember you use Handlebars for the templates.

You should also read this: [Information about components](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ember-components-a-deep-dive--net-35551)

I hope that this helps you.